# How can I start urxvt as a child of a running XWin instance?

Tags: cygwin, x-windows, cygwin-x

I have configured XWin to start automatically at logon, this gives me a tray icon where I can launch  X apps that will be children of the XWin instance and have their environment correclty set just like I was running in a Unix based OS(XWin is started through a login shell that setups the environment).

The problem is that I can't find a way to launch x apps(urxvt) as children of that XWin instance. This breaks interactive shells startup since I have to use login shells for every terminal I need to open.

How can I simulate the XWin tray icon application menu action?(Eg: from a start menu shortcut)

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with the XWin-Menu, you can expand that by editing `/etc/X11/system.XWinrc`:

```
 // Make some menus...
 menu apps {
          xterm   exec    "xterm"
          "Emacs" exec    "emacs"
          notepad exec    notepad
          xload   exec    "xload -display %display%"  # Comment
          urxvt   exec    "urxvt"                     # <- added by me
 }
```

After saving, don't forget to `Reload XWinrc` to apply changes.

---

However, I use the following approach (I wanted to pin URxvt to the taskbar) -- it sounds really cumbersome, and it probably is... but hey it's Windows `;)`

First, I created a `c:\cygwin\cygwin.bat`

```
@echo off
C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin
zsh --login -i -c 'urxvt'
```

Adapt path and shell to your situation.

To configure the appearance of URxvt I use these lines in `.Xdefaults`:

```
URxvt.borderColor: black
URxvt.internalBorder: 4 
URxvt.background: black
URxvt.foreground: orange
! URxvt.inheritPixmap: True
! URxvt.shading: 40
! URxvt.tintColor: orange
URxvt.scrollBar: False
URxvt.geometry: 150x60+500+100
URxvt.font: -*-clean-bold-r-normal-*-17-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

change to your preferences or uncomment with `!` if you like the default.

Then I created a shortcut (also in `C:\cygwin`) so that I can customize the icon and renamed that shortcut to `ZSH_tray`. This shortcut gets pinned to the taskbar.

My main problem was (and probably yours, too) is, that there is a shell windows in addition to the URxvt window. To prevent that I use [Tray-It](http://www.heise.de/download/tray-it-trayit-1131803.html):

1. Install & start Tray-It
2. Start URxvt via the shortcut
3. In Tray-IT:

   - right click the corresponding entry -> Place in Systray
   - Edit -> Profiles
   - Config according to screenshots
4. Hide Tray-It itself and start it with windows (Edit -> Options)

[image: config of trayit]

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not what I meant. My problem is that I want to start the rxvt process as child of the login shell used to start XWin, so it will correctly inherit the environment I usually setup on Unixes. Btw to run X apps without the DOS window just run it with the cygwin 'run.exe' executable (man run).

Comment: @ThiadodeArruda: Oh yes, I didn't get your point first, sorry. I think your edited question is clearer now, but unfortunately I don't have a solution for that. -- And thanks for the hint with `run`, my presented workaround looks stupid now...